# Migrate write data from ArangoDB to OracleDB

Tags: oracle, arangodb, data-migration

Recently we found some instability issues with ArangoDB. So we planned to migrate write data from ArangoDB to OracleDB. Anyone know how can we migrate ArangoDB data to oracle DB?

Comment: when i searched on google,there will not any driver between oracle and ArangoDB. So may you can use java-python or any prog.language to select and insert road.

Comment: @Jikku Varghese: Please file an issue here and describe the instability issues: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/new Bugs in ArangoDB are patched as fast as possible by the core team.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/1.0.1/trianglify.min.js"></script>
  <script>jekyllBootstrapDoc.trianglify('#0074d9', '#001f3f', 'jQuery QueryBuilder');</script>
   
  <script>
  var divIndex = 1;
  
  function addBuilderFromBtn(){
    var divObj = document.createElement('div');
 divObj.id = 'query-builder_'+divIndex;
 var oldIdnex = divIndex-1;
 document.getElementById('query-builder_'+oldIdnex).appendChild(divObj);
 addBuilder();
  }
  
  function addBuilder(){
 renderBuilder(divIndex, getRules());
 divIndex++;
  }

Comment: function reset(){
  for(var i=1; i<divIndex; i++){
  $('#query-builder_'+i).queryBuilder('reset');
   }
 }
 
 function setRules(){
  for(var i=1; i<divIndex; i++){
  $('#query-builder_'+i).queryBuilder('setRules', getRules());
   }
 }
 
 function getRulesObj(){
   var result = $('#query-builder_1').queryBuilder('getRules');
   if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
   }
 }